# Check if a user has isAdmin true

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to make an isAdmin() function that will check if the current user has "isAdmin: true" in the mongodb.

server.js

```
app.get('/api/isadmin', function (req, res) {
  User.findById(req.user, function (err, user) {
    if (req.user.isAdmin == true) {
        res.send(user);
    } else {
        return res.status(400).send({ message: 'User is not Admin' });
    }
  });
});
```

AdminCtrl.js

```
angular.module('App')
  .controller('AdminCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $auth) {
      $http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/isadmin')
          .then(function (res) {
             $scope.isAdmin = res.data;
      }
 });
```

when I access the page /admin it throws "cannot read property 'isAdmin' of null" in the if inside app.get. Why is this occuring, and what is the optimal way for me to make this isAdmin function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the variable sent back to you, but still the req.

```
app.get('/api/isadmin', function (req, res) {
  User.findById(req.user, function (err, user) {
    if (user.isAdmin == true) {
        res.send(user);
    } else {
        return res.status(400).send({ message: 'User is not Admin' });
    }
  });
});
```

Maybe this should work (assuming you are returned if the user isAdmin)

Comment: You are not sending anything alongside to your GET request. this is why req.user is empty ?

Comment: It seems to work now for some reason. How would I make a function that checks that api if the user is admin?

Comment: I'm not aware of your app, but wouldn't the best way to check that is by verifying if the user is an admin on every action that requires so ?

Comment: What I'm looking to do is make a function in angular that I can call with ng-if to only have admins have access to certain pages/buttons

Comment: You should call that function once when the user logs in, and keep it within a service. Look on the internet for authentication service examples in angular. This is where you should keep all user related data and functions (login, logout, ect). In your controllers, you could set the isAdmin property of the user to the scope, or whatever. And in your views you can then use `ng-if="user.isAdmin"`

Comment: Thanks! Will have a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

try following

```
angular.module('App')
  .controller('AdminCtrl',['$scope','$http','$auth', function ($scope, $http, $auth) {
      $http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/isadmin')
          .then(function (res) {
             $scope.isAdmin = res.data;
      }
 }]);
```